# How to reference a script's directory when calling additional, standalone scripts that must also reference their own directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

### TL;DR

Hi, I have two hypothetical scripts, where each needs to reference its own, unique directory.

How should I generally (i.e. from a bash script template) define the script's unique directory such that the `$DIR` variable isn't reset?

### Samples

#### Code

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/test/prj1/script1.sh
DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd -P)
echo "script1 is located in $DIR"
source "$DIR/../prj2/script2.sh"
echo "Sh*t, script1 is not located in ${DIR}!
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/test/prj2/script2.sh
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd -P)"
echo "But script2 is located in ${DIR}"
```

#### Returns

*Full script paths obfuscated for simplicity*

```
script1 is located in ~/test/prj1
But script2 is located in ~/test/prj2
Sh*t, script1 is not located in ~/test/prj2!
```

### Background

I am trying to follow good, standard practices for a library of .sh scripts that I am creating. I want each to define its own directory by default. But I want the different scripts to source one another as needed without messing the `$DIR` variable up.

Katas in [Defensive Bash Programming](http://kfirlavi.herokuapp.com/) recommends setting the directory name as a `readonly` var at the start of any script. But, this doesn't seem to play nicely when multiple scripts are sourcing one another with a different `$DIR` as `readonly` is intentionally not easily reassigned. And the directory of prj1/script1.sh is different than prj2/script2.sh.

Comment: I don't understand. Have you immediately after submitting the question answered it yourself? Sorry if I'm mistaken. I haven't been here for a long time.

Comment: @Alireza Yes. I wanted to share what I've come up with so far with everyone. I view this as a good practice because 1) it shows others what I've come up with so far, 2) encourages research/testing before question asking, 3) helps folks (hopefully) who have the same question.

Comment: ^ But, I'm still asking the question because peer review is essential for any scientific endeavor. Perhaps someone has a better way.

Comment: That makes sense, but from the little and probably expired experience I have, the research and unsatisfactory solutions are added to the question itself. This would be easier to discover for the people that read it. Unless you come up with a new solution after you send the question.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Though, it is encouraged by Stack Exchange per https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: You are right, there is no denying this :D

Comment: No sweat. It might even be a new feature :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been doing:

### Option 1 (Bad, Quick and Dirty)

One (bad) option is to always assign the script's directory a different variable. So, script1.sh would assign`DIR1=...` and script2.sh would assign `DIR2=...`. But that is messy. You'd have to remember to call the right `DIR`, and not scalable as your library gets bigger.

### Option 2 (Better)

This option defines the script's directory as a local variable in a parent `run()` function. The only potential downside I can see is that local is undefined in POSIX. So it should work as long as:

1. POSIX isn't used
2. `local` is used, per below code
3. The `body` of the script is called from within the parent `run` of the script, per below code. In this way the local variable is inherited by the sub-function.

#### Code

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/repo/prj1/script1.sh
run () {
    local DIR
    DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd -P)
    echo "First, we are in $DIR"
    body () {
        echo "script1 is located in $DIR"
        source "$DIR/../prj2/script2.sh"
        echo "Hurrah, script1 is located in ${DIR}!"
    }
    body
}
run
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/repo/prj2/script2.sh
run () {
    local DIR
    DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd -P)
    body () {
        echo "But script2 is located in ${DIR}"
    }
    body
}
run
```

#### Returns

*Full script paths obfuscated for simplicity*

```
First, we are in ~/test/prj1
script1 is located in ~/test/prj1
But script2 is located in ~/test/prj2
Hurrah, script1 is located in ~/test/prj1!
```